# Highcharts: Hide chart but not date range selection or zoom

Tags: highcharts

In HighCharts/HighStock I'd like to be able to click a button and hide only the graph section, but leave the date selection tools. To illustrate my point, here are a couple screenshots:

Default view:

[image: Default view]

Now, after clicking a button, hide the chart but leave the other elements:

[image: After button click]

We would like to do this because we'd like to use the date slider as a date range filter for the overall error page, but only show the graph when a button is clicked.

I tried inspecting the elements to just do a manual hide/show with jQuery, but it doesn’t seem like that is going to work too well. Is there any built in functionality to accomplish this?

Or does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YzFHF/

It's basically the demo with some changed properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can achieve that by combining:

- setting charts height via `chart.setSize(null, value);`
- using `axis.update` which was introduced in Highcharts 3.0 Beta

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/YzFHF/1/).